# is there a limit on PHPExcel row height

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am producing a xls (excel5 format) spreadsheet with PHPExcel. It works great except for one minor problem. I have three groups of text data that appear one after the other in the column. They are in the format

```
Item 1
a
b
c

Item 2
a
b
c

Item 3
a
b
c
```

All lines are separated by a new line (\n). The problem is that only the first two items appear. I use the following to set the row height to auto:

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);
```

I've tried setting the rowheight to 1000, while I get a tall row I don't get more data. I have printed out the string and examined it and there are no funky characters. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: the better question would be "does excel have a row height limit". PHPExcel can't do anything that Excel can't do itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't simply assume that setting the default will work if individual rows have already been set with a height. It's better to allow the default to do its job for most rows, and to explicitly set those that you need to set

Use

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(123);
```

to set each row that you need to set

And the maximum row height is 409

Comment: Thanks. I think the 409 limit is what I am hitting, any idea of how to get longer data into a cell? This is a dynamic SS generated by a web site for exporting the data. I wanted it formatted instead of using a CSV file.

Comment: If you need cells that are more than 409 points (546 pixels) high, then you probably aren't really after a spreadsheet; but you can always make two adjacent rows 409 points each and then merge cells to give an 818 point high block

Comment: Good idea. The users want spreadsheet output is the problem. Is that an excel limit or a PHPExcel limit.

Comment: The 409.50 points (546 pixels) limit is an MS Excel limit.... PHPExcel doesn't actually validate that the entered value falls below that limit